# Antlr Exception : there is no serialized ATN

Tags: java, antlr4

I am trying to understand how to use `ParseTreePattern` in order to get specific element from my input.
So first I tried the following :

```
 ParseTreePattern p = parser.compileParseTreePattern("<NODE>", GraphParser.RULE_input);
```

where `NODE` is a token in my grammar and I end up with

```
Unknown token NODE in pattern: <NODE>
```

So why this token is not recognized as it is a part of my grammar?

When I the tree pattern with rule name `<quantifier>` which is again part of my grammar I end up with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: there is no serialized ATN
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Recognizer.getSerializedATN(Recognizer.java:134)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.getATNWithBypassAlts(Parser.java:458)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.pattern.ParseTreePatternMatcher.tokenize(ParseTreePatternMatcher.java:414)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.pattern.ParseTreePatternMatcher.compile(ParseTreePatternMatcher.java:218)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.compileParseTreePattern(Parser.java:506)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.compileParseTreePattern(Parser.java:492)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

So what is the meaning of the second error? Just to clarify that I am using ANTLR 4.2 (obviously `ParseTreePattern` isn't a part of the 4.1 library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your grammar was generated with ANTLR 4.1. We took great care to make sure that existing code for users upgrading from 4.1 to 4.2 wouldn't break, but to use the new features in 4.2 you'll need to regenerate your parsers with the latest version of the tool.

If you aren't already doing so, I highly recommend you integrate the parser generation process into your build system (e.g. Maven, Ant) to ensure that the correct version is always the one in use.